# RDP RemoteApp works with IPv6 but not IPv4?

Tags: networking, remote-desktop, ipv6

I have a Windows 7 Professional machine that I'm using as a RDP server. I've used [RemoteAppTool](http://www.kimknight.net/remoteapptool) to generate a .RDP file to connect to a RemoteApp application.

Below is the .RDP file:

```
allow desktop composition:i:1
allow font smoothing:i:1
alternate full address:s:Foobar
alternate shell:s:rdpinit.exe
devicestoredirect:s:*
disableremoteappcapscheck:i:1
drivestoredirect:s:*
full address:s:Foobar
prompt for credentials on client:i:1
promptcredentialonce:i:0
redirectcomports:i:1
redirectdrives:i:1
remoteapplicationmode:i:1
remoteapplicationname:s:PeachRA
remoteapplicationprogram:s:||PeachRA
span monitors:i:1
use multimon:i:1
```

This RDP file works fine from a Windows 10 client machine. However, it does not work from either a Macbook Pro (using the Microsoft Remote Desktop client) or a Chromebook (using the Xtralogic RDP client) - it cannot find the server on these machines.

The .rdp file has `full address` set to `Foobar`.

However, I cannot ping `Foobar` from the Macbook Pro. I tried pinging this from the Windows client machine, and it seems to resolve to a IPv6 address:

```
C:\Users\AVS Office>ping Foobar

Pinging Foobar [fe80::d8f8:80f1:1492:9ee3%9] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from fe80::d8f8:80f1:1492:9ee3%9: time<1ms
Reply from fe80::d8f8:80f1:1492:9ee3%9: time<1ms
Reply from fe80::d8f8:80f1:1492:9ee3%9: time<1ms
```

This is the ipconfig from the Windows 10 client machine:

```
C:\Users\AVS Office>ipconfig /all

Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : Office-XXX-2
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : D8-50-E6-BA-XX-XX
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::197f:d1f5:8fd2:3418%9(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.1.1.11(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.0.0.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.1.1.1
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 249057510
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1A-D0-4B-B5-D8-50-E6-BA-89-51
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.1.1.1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : VMware Virtual Ethernet Adapter for VMnet1
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-50-56-C0-00-01
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::4850:26e2:aa65:f8fb%5(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.48.1(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Wednesday, 16 November, 2016 4:24:29 PM
   Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Tuesday, 22 November, 2016 11:24:37 PM
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.48.254
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 67129430
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-1A-D0-4B-B5-D8-50-E6-BA-89-51
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Tunnel adapter isatap.{F2493FFC-B6B8-4BE4-BF58-E26DC84389CB}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.{8464D47A-BE0F-46F8-BDE2-3055AF381849}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

I believe the Foobar server also has an IPv4 address (10.1.1.2) - I've tried setting the .RDP file to point to this. It does connect, but the RemoteApp feature doesn't work - it seems to open a full-screen RDP connection.

Firstly, why is the Windows client able to connect via IPv6, but the MBP and Chromebook are not?

Secondly, why would connecting via the IPv6 address make a difference, versus using a IPv4 address, specifically for the RDP RemoteApp feature?

Comment: Firewall rules?

Comment: @Lenniey - I don't believe so - the MBP doesn't have a firewall enabled. For Chromebooks, I'm pretty sure these don't either.

Comment: No I meant the firewall rules could block the IPv4 RDP connection but allow IPv6. Also: if your Win7 machine registers its IPv6 address in DNS, you obviously connect via IPv6. Do your other clients (MBP / Chromebook) have IPv6 enabled at all?

Comment: Interesting - so you're saying check the firewall on the Windows 7 Professional RDP server? Sure.

However, the thing is - I can do a normal full-screen RDP session to that machine via the IPv4 address (10.1.1.2) - but it's the RemoteApp connection that doesn't seem to work correctly.

MBP and Chromebook do support IPv6 in theory - not sure why they're not picking up a IPv6 address here in this case though.

Comment: I'm a bit confused...did you find the error? Does it _work_ at all, even if not like you wanted it to?

Comment: No - I haven't found the error.

The problem description is - normal RDP session (i.e. the whole desktop) works via IPv4. However, RemoteApp (i.e. single application) only seems to work via IPv6 - or perhaps it's the Windows client (which uses IPv6).